# Django Ajax CSRF verification failed

Tags: django, ajax, django-csrf

Here is my class, extending from `from django.views.generic import View`:

```
class ClassView(ProtectedView, View):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.client = get_default_client()

    def get(self, request, item_remove, item_replacement):
        ... code ...
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def post(self, request, item_remove, item_replacement):
        ... code ...
        return JsonResponse({})
```

`ProtectedView` mixin:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(superuser_required, name='dispatch')
class ProtectedView(object):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ajax call :

```
        this.utils._ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: `/api/shortage/${this.item_remove}/${this.item_replacement}`,
            data: {
                item_type: 'product_bundle',
                delivery: productBundles,
            }
        })
```

Ajax object :

```
    _ajax(req) {
        const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }

        this.$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {

                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        const ajax$ = this.$.ajax({
            url: req.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: req.method,
            data: req.data,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
        });

        return ajax$;
    }
```

Headers in request

```
{ 
   'Content-Length':'50',
   'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   'Host':'localhost:8000',
   'Connection':'keep-alive',
   'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
   'Origin':'http://localhost:8000',
   'X-Csrftoken':'QEu0E1GTrbmEfqK9Pv4mB03rliVQAHSmC6p95YOUjZHPJCr8hu42d6cTe3BrTdw9',
   'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
   'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Mobile Safari/537.36',
   'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
   'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
   'Referer':'http://localhost:8000/admin/shortage',
   'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
   'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
   'Cookie':'csrftoken=QEu0E1GTrbmEfqK9Pv4mB03rliVQAHSmC6p95YOUjZHPJCr8hu42d6cTe3BrTdw9; pnctest=1; logglytrackingsession=37c9453d-1b2c-443d-9a8e-167c8576cb8b; sessionId=68a017ab-a1d5-43a3-93c3-4df44b3851c3; sessionid=zl2k7hwechu0uprq4tqw66znc91op5ua'
}
```

CSRF Token is clearly contained in headers, but still, the method always return `(403) CSRF verification failed`

Any idea to fix this issue? Thanks.

Edit: Since this part is still in development, I added `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')` to my class to keep going. Obviously I don't recommend this as a solution.

Comment: Set `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` to False. Read at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false

Comment: @FaisalManzer, can you post this as answer and not as comment so I can validate your solution ? This is working. ```CSRF_USE_SESSIONS``` was True in my settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` to False.
Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false